# MYSQL not receiving data from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I am trying to send data from input to a my sqldata base. Here is the coding for it trying to send the information to the database. It doesn't appear in the database; what is wrong with the coding?

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect(/*hostname*/"localhost",
                    /*username*/"user",
                    /*password*/"pass",
                    /*database name*/"dbase");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$a =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['a']);
$b =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b']);
$c =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b']);
$d =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['d']);
$e =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['e']);
$f =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['f']);
$g = 10 + ($e - $f);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'mensscore', (Name, Club, Level, App, Score);
    VALUES ('".$a."',
            '".$b."',
            '".$c."',
            '".$d."'
            '".$g."')");
    ?>
```

Comment: You are mixing mysql_* and mysqli_*.

Comment: Also, your SQL query has multiple errors.

Comment: Remove ',' after table name. It should be  `INSERT INTO mensscore (Name, Club.. ` instead of `INSERT INTO 'mensscore', (Name, Club.. `. And also use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysql_query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing mysql and mysqli. Change:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'mensscore', (Name, Club, Level, App, Score);
    VALUES ('".$a."',
            '".$b."',
            '".$c."',
            '".$d."'
            '".$g."')");
```

To:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `mensscore` (Name, Club, Level, App, Score)
    VALUES ('$a',
            '$b',
            '$c',
            '$d',
            '$g'
    );");
```

Also see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) and [PHP: mysqli_stmt - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) because using POST is not always safe as people can do SQL injection.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\judge\MG\score.php on line 47

Comment: @TheOkayMan But it has two parameters. Try again because edited

Comment: OK now please select as working answer by clicking on the tick. And also please upvote to set as worked answer. @TheOkayMan

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in the query. Firstly use `mysqli_query()` as here, you are using mysqli. Remove the unwanted , and ; from the query and try with this,

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO 'mensscore' (Name, Club, Level, App, Score)
    VALUES ('$a',
            '$b',
            '$c',
            '$d'
            '$g')");
```

Comment: include `$con` as parameter in the mysqli_query

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO mensscore (Name, Club, Level, App, Score)VALUES ('".$a."',
>         '".$b."',
>         '".$c."',
>         '".$d."',
>         '".$g."')");
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO mensscore  (Name, Club, Level, App, Score)
    VALUES ('{$a}','{$b}','{$c}','{$d}','{$g}'");
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","dbase");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $a =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['a']);
    $b =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b']);
    $c =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['b']);
    $d =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['d']);
    $e =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['e']);
    $f =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['f']);
    $g = 10 + ($e - $f);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mensscore(Name, Club, Level, App, Score)VALUES('".$a."','".$b."','".$c."','".$d."''".$g."')";
    $result = $con->query($sql) or die("Error executing query" . mysqli_error($conn));
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. don't single quote the table name `mensscore`
2. don't use semicolon before `VALUES` keyword